# How to get the content returned by link element ref="stylesheet"?

Tags: javascript, css, html

let's say I have those 2 style

```
<head>
  <title>My page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">    
  <style>
    //style here ...
  </style>
</head>
```

To get the content of my style, I'll do something like:

```
var styleSheets = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].innerHTML;
```

What about if I want to get the content of what's being sent to the `<link>` element? I want the **style** that is being sent to the page as *text* after `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">` has been processed.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [document.StyleSheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/styleSheets) to get the content.

It gives you a StyleSheetList Object. Interesting to play with it in the browserconsole.

```js
// document.styleSheets (StyleSheetList)
const mainCSS = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules; // (CSSRuleList) (I take the first link in this example)
let mainCSSText = '';
[...mainCSS].forEach(rule => mainCSSText += rule.cssText);

console.log(mainCSSText)
```

Here is an example for reading out the document.StyleSheets:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zq7zkvmk7l?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js)

I got some problems with cdn linked css.

Comment: It seems like `StyleSheet` (object) doesn't have a `cssText` or `cssRules` property.

Comment: it does, but not directly. document.styleSheets gives you a List (array like). Thats why i used document.styleSheets[0] to take the first link-element. I'm not 100% sure, if i understand your needs. Hope my example can help you:  https://codesandbox.io/s/zq7zkvmk7l?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`let rootStyle = document.documentElement.style;`

Also, if you use CSS variables you can get & set them by doing this:

`let varname = rootStyle.getPropertyValue('--yourpropertyname')`

`rootStyle.setProperty('--yourpropertyname', yourvaluehere);`

Comment: I'm not trying to get the content of the style. I want the content of the `<link href="" rel="stylesheet">` element.